# How to get website link stats?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, statistics, facebook-fql

I heard there is a way to get stats for URLs from Facebook using FQL. Is there a way to do this using the Open Graph?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can retrieve link stats from Graph API endpoint.

For example, accessing https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://example.com will get you a response like this:

```js
{
   "id": "http://example.com",
   "shares": 47068
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you!  It also returns "comments": 3, but not likes as far as I can tell.  Any idea how to return likes for a particular url?

Comment: @ChrisPhelps It is not achievable in Graph API v1.0, AFAIK. Please note that the "shares" count above is actually the sum of likes, shares and comments. (See the result of this FQL query: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url%2C%20share_count%2C%20like_count%2C%20comment_count%2C%20total_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%27)